# Google Map not loading AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show a google map on my AngularJs app. I used below code and when run, map not displayed. Just a blank page. No errors on browser console.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/51597/)

HTML Code

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="google-maps"></div>
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('google-maps');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}

$timeout(function(){
  initialize();
}, 100);
```

Also I have this code in index.html file

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&libraries=places"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling initialize() inside document.ready:

```
$(initialize);
```

Also give a width and height to your container div.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3741cde/)